# asus rt-n16 weird thing - turns itself off (from time to time)

Tags: router, dd-wrt, modem

until now everything worked ok long time, but I started to have weird problem. 
My specification: asus rt-n16, DD-WRT v24-sp2 (07/24/13) mega - build 22118

In the last week my router stopped working, "turned" itself off twice (4AM, then after few day again at 6:20AM). All lights were turned off, it looks like it is completely off (can't do anything, my network is down)

When I unplug power cable from router and then plug it back, it started to work again, lights are on, everything is working for few days great. (after few day scenario repeated)

What can be the issue?

Comment: Maybe it is overheating? I had one router that would get very hot (for no obvious reason) and eventually died completely.

Comment: Standard troubleshooting... this are either hardware or software.Try the easy stuff first, default the router and reconfigure it. If the problem persists update to latest DD-WRT or similar firmware, and if the problem still continues its probably bad hardware.

Comment: I think it's hardware issue. Now my router "died" and I am not able to turn it on (as I was able to do it few hour ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I replaced 470uF/16V capacitor and it is working again :)

Comment: Please share procedure and steps please. Thanks.

Comment: It was long time ago, but these pics should help you https://www.google.com/search?q=asus+rt-n16+capacitor+replacement&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=&biw=1536&bih=710